# Polynomial multiplication is associative

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, power-series, associativity

Let $A$ be a ring and $f,g,h\in A[X]$. I want to show that $(fg)h=f(gh)$, where $(xy)_n:=\sum_{n=j+k}x_jy_k$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Attempt: Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I have to show that $((fg)h)_n=(f(gh))_n$. By definition
$$((fg)h)_n=\sum_{n=j+k}(fg)_jh_k=\sum_{n=j+k}\left(\sum_{j=s+t}f_sg_t\right)h_k=\sum_{n=j+k}\sum_{j=s+t}(f_sg_t)h_k.$$
Presumably that last expression is equal to $\sum_{n=(s+t)+k}(f_sg_t)h_k$. But why? What is the formal justification?

Comment: Hello, I was having trouble to understand the same thing, the book I was reading used different notation for this same thing, I believe the question I posted can help you a bit, take a look on this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3841134/defining-a-summation-with-an-equation-as-index?noredirect=1#comment7926669_3841134