# Defining a summation with an equation as index

Tags: summation, notation

Im trying to solve a question which is stated as follows.

**Question:** If $f$ and $g$ are functions defined for non negative integers and with values in $A$, propose a suitable definition for $\displaystyle\sum_{i+j=n}f(i)g(j) = f(0)g(n)+f(1)g(n-1)+...+f(n)g(0)$.

Do the same for $\displaystyle\sum_{i+j+k=n}f(i)g(j)h(k)$, if $h$ is another function defined for nonnegative integers and with values in $A$.

**My atempt:** Looking at the format of the expression described in the first example I noticed that $i$ ranges from $0$ to $n$ and using the equality $i+j=n$ it follows that $j=n-i$, therefore I think the answer to the first case is $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n}f(i)g(n-i)$.

But I dont know if im reading it in the right way, I dont managed to give a definition to the second case, when we have something like $\displaystyle\sum_{i+j+k=n}f(i)g(j)h(k)$, it means the sum of all products where sum of indexes equal to $n$? and how can I give it another definition with the common notation with start and end values for the finite sum?

Comment: You are reading it in the right way, and you can write $$\sum_{\substack{(i,j,k) \in \mathbb{N}^3 \\ i + j + k = n}}f(i)g(j)h(k) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n} \sum_{j = 0}^{n-i} f(i)g(j)h(n-i-j)\,.$$

Comment: I can see that $i + j + (n-i-j) = n$, but I dot not understand how can I goes from the left side to the right side of your answer, It is a direct definition or I can follow some steps to reach this final form?

Comment: You can take an intermediate step, $$\sum_{i = 0}^{n} f(i)\sum_{j + k = n-i} g(j)h(k)\,,$$ and use the first part for the inner sum.

Comment: I still having some difficult here, I just tried to follow the same approach in the first case, but I know Im missing something, Starting with $\sum_{i+j+k=n}f(i)g(j)h(k)$ I first thinked to let $i$ range from to 0 to n, then I got $\sum_{i=0}^{n}f(i)...$ and I know that If $i+j+k=n$ then $j+k=n-i$ But I dont get the reasoning to use another summation and got stucked again.

Comment: It may help if you explicitly write down all the triples to sum over for $n = 3$ or $n = 4$ (these are small enough to be done by hand, but large enough that one can see what's going on), and then group them according to their first component.